# Flutter parse GMT

Tags: flutter

Hello，I have a question!
I want to parse Time, GMT to Milliseconds。
for example:`Thu, 10 Oct 2019 02:05:09 GMT.`
I try `DateTime.parse("Thu, 10 Oct 2019 02:05:09 GMT")`
i get this error

> Exception caught by widgets library  The following FormatException was
>   thrown building GroupPage(dirty, state: _GroupPage#cb39c):  invalid
>   date format  Thu, 10 oct 2019 02:05:09 GMT

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `HttpDate` class to parse this.

Example:

```
DateTime parsedDate = HttpDate.parse("Thu, 10 Oct 2019 02:05:09 GMT");
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.parse` can parse only ISO 8601 dates, not an arbitrary ones. From docs:

> The function parses a subset of ISO 8601 which includes the subset
>   accepted by RFC 3339.
>
> Examples of accepted strings:
>
> ```
> "2012-02-27 13:27:00"
> "2012-02-27 13:27:00.123456z"
> "2012-02-27 13:27:00,123456z"
> "20120227 13:27:00"
> "20120227T132700"
> "20120227"
> "+20120227"
> "2012-02-27T14Z"
> "2012-02-27T14+00:00"
> "-123450101 00:00:00 Z": in the year -12345.
> "2002-02-27T14:00:00-0500": Same as "2002-02-27T19:00:00Z"
> ```

`DateTime.parse` method is not an option for your date string, unless you get it in ISO 8601 format.

Answer (score 0):

The `intl` package can parse relatively flexible dates and times: https://pub.dev/packages/intl#date-formatting-and-parsing